# Loop through all Outlook inboxes including shared inboxes error

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have code that will search through a user's Outlook and reply to an email depending on the Subject phrase you input in the worksheet cell. I did have it working a couple days ago, but now I can not seem to get it to work (was deleted). Once run, an error message will continuously display for code line "Set olitems = flrd.Items", saying "Object variable or With block variable not set". I think the problem is the End if but wherever I place it either the code does nothing or the same error displays.

The only other problem with the working code (when it worked) was that it populated more than once. I wish it to populate only one time.

```
Sub Display()

Dim Fldr As Outlook.Folder
Dim olfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olReply As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
Dim i As Integer
Dim signature As String
Dim allStores As Stores
Dim storeInbox As Folder
Dim j As Long

Set allStores = Session.Stores

For j = 1 To allStores.count
On Error Resume Next
Debug.Print i & " DisplayName - " & allStores(i).DisplayName
On Error GoTo 0

Set storeInbox = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set storeInbox = allStores(i).GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not storeInbox Is Nothing Then
End if
     Set olItems = Fldr.Items

olItems.Sort "[Received]", True

For i = 1 To olItems.count
    signature = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\"

    If Dir(signature, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
        signature = signature & Dir$(signature & "*.htm")
    Else
        signature = ""
    End If

    signature = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(signature).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2).ReadAll

    Set olMail = olItems(i)

    If InStr(olMail.Subject, Worksheets("Checklist Form").Range("B8")) <> 0 Then
        If Not olMail.Categories = "Executed" Then
            Set olReply = olMail.ReplyAll

            With olReply
                .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:14.5'>" & "Hi Everyone," & _
                    "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:14.5'>" & "Workflow ID:" & " " & _
                    Worksheets("Checklist Form").Range("B6") & "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:14.5'>" & _
                    Worksheets("Checklist Form").Range("B11") & "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:14.5'>" & _
                    "Regards," & "</p><br>" & signature & .HTMLBody
                .Display
                .Subject = "RO Finalized WF:" & Worksheets("Checklist Form").Range("B6") & " " & _
                    Worksheets("Checklist Form").Range("B2") & " -" & Worksheets("Fulfillment Checklist").Range("B3")
            End With

            Exit For
            olMail.Categories = "Executed"

        End If
    End If

Next i
 Set Fldr = StoreInbox

Next

ExitRoutine:
Set allStores = Nothing
Set storeInbox = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` line.
Secondly, `Fldr` variable is never set. Did you mean to use `storeInbox` variable instead?

```
Sub Display()

Dim Fldr As Outlook.Folder
Dim olfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olReply As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
Dim i As Integer
Dim signature As String
Dim allStores As Stores
Dim storeInbox As Folder
Dim j As Long

Set allStores = Session.Stores

For j = 1 To allStores.count
On Error Resume Next
Debug.Print i & " DisplayName - " & allStores(i).DisplayName
On Error GoTo 0

Set storeInbox = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set storeInbox = allStores(i).GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not storeInbox Is Nothing Then

     Set olItems = Fldr.Items

olItems.Sort "[Received]", True

For i = 1 To olItems.count
    signature = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\"

    If Dir(signature, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
        signature = signature & Dir$(signature & "*.htm")
    Else
        signature = ""
    End If

    signature = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(signature).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2).ReadAll

    Set olMail = olItems(i)

    If InStr(olMail.Subject, Worksheets("Checklist Form").Range("B8")) <> 0 Then
        If Not olMail.Categories = "Executed" Then
            Set olReply = olMail.ReplyAll

            With olReply
                .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:14.5'>" & "Hi Everyone," & _
                    "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:14.5'>" & "Workflow ID:" & " " & _
                    Worksheets("Checklist Form").Range("B6") & "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:14.5'>" & _
                    Worksheets("Checklist Form").Range("B11") & "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:14.5'>" & _
                    "Regards," & "</p><br>" & signature & .HTMLBody
                .Display
                .Subject = "RO Finalized WF:" & Worksheets("Checklist Form").Range("B6") & " " & _
                    Worksheets("Checklist Form").Range("B2") & " -" & Worksheets("Fulfillment Checklist").Range("B3")
            End With

            Exit For
            olMail.Categories = "Executed"

        End If
    End If

Next i

End if

Next

ExitRoutine:
Set allStores = Nothing
Set storeInbox = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178235/discussion-on-answer-by-dmitry-streblechenko-loop-through-all-outlook-inboxes-in).